# Testing parallel IGBT module

Tags: measurement, inverter, igbt

A single NPN IGBT chip can usually be tested by a 9V battery between gate and emitter.

However opening up a [larger module](http://www.semikron.com/dl/service-support/downloads/download/semikron-datasheet-skiip-513-gd172-3duw-v3-20451231) reveals many IGBT modules in parallel. I`ve seen some inverters using several of these in parallel again, together maybe 200 IGBT chips in parallel for a single phase.

In the scenarios of only parts of the IGBT have blown. Be it either 199/200 or 5/200 and assuming no visible damage. Is there any way of measuring if this is the case? The 9V battery test would perform as if no problem was present. Opening up the module for inspection ruins the module.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgrVWt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is that scenario really a problem? If 199/200 of the IGBT's have blown, the last one isn't likely to last another microsecond under load. The challenging case is when 5 out of 200 IGBT's are damaged.

Comment: You are right. 5/200 damaged is the more likely problem to have. The 199/200 was more to make a point that a single survivor ruins the simple test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tests you can perform to gauge the "health" of a module. Essentially you need to characterise a number of healthy modules. The minimum number of failed devices essentially comes down to device tolerances and measurement accuracy.

What you need to consider is what types of failures are you looking for?

- shorted gate-emitter. can be detected via G-E impedance
- shorted collector-emitter. can be detected via C-E impedance
- open gate-emitter (bondwire, damage...). Can be detected by a change in characteristics
- etc...

There are four characteristics worth determining for the complete module

1. \$C_{iss}\$
2. \$C_{rss}\$
3. \$C_{oss}\$
4. fwd voltage drop.

An IGBT die datasheet will usually provide the small signal \$C_{iss}\$,  \$C_{rss}\$, \$C_{oss}\$. You cannot just take these values and multiply them by 200 as there will be additional stray capacitance within the module under test.

Once these values are measured & captured for a number of healthy modules, you will be able to determine a spread. The number of failed devices you could possibly detect then comes down to  the deviation. The loss of one device may still fall within the possible healthy range. 2? 3? once you have some empirical evidence you can come up with a detectable number.

The final method is to mount the module on a heatsink and heat the heatsink to a given temperature (50C, 75C). A significant temperature above ambient to mitigate change in ambient when testing on different days.

Gate ON the IGBT stacks (9V or the correct 15V) but ensure you measure the gate voltage with reasonable accuracy (not a 9V battery when it is really supplying 8V...). Then with a high current source with a resistive shunt to measure the forward current accurately, apply this source Collector --> Emitter.

Measure the Collector->Emitter voltage.  The actual current to be applied should be say... 50% of the maximum device current.  With the loss of one or many devices this \$V_{ce}\$ will rise.

Comment: Great answer! Could you elaborate on what characteristics to look for on open gate-emitter bondwire problems? Just lower GE capacitance perhaps...?

Comment: exactly that. once you have determined Ciss, Crss, Coss, you can determine the small signal Cge, Cce, Ccg. You will see a reduction if one is damaged. The level of acceptable reduction (with regards to component variance) will help facilitate a PASS or a FAIL

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit shows mosfets but ok.

You won't ever see an IGBT with 99% health... 80% health and etc.

No point testing each datasheet parameters against the actual device; they can vary significantly from device to device. And by the time you see a parameter way outside what the datasheet says, your device has already  failed normally open, normally closed, or obviously enough that you know its damaged.

Comment: First point: You are right. At the time of writing the circuit lab didnt have an igbt option, so used mosfet for the visuals. Second point desperatly needs  citation from something.  At least something like "I personally saw implemented health control once on x drivers, yet still they eventually blew up without any warning."